# How the web application to achieve the schedule task on a shared host?

Tags: asp.net, scheduler, quartz.net

As far as I know, the `quartz.net` scheduler is started in the `global.asax`. That's to say, `quartz.net` scheduler does not work unless someone visits the website. This is not a safe way because the scheduler thread can be killed by rebooting server or the process in the IIS pool being terminated, and the scheduler thread will remain unstarted until someone visits the website again.

We could use windows scheduler to solve this problem. But we are using a **shared host** and we cannot write a service or a sql server job or schedule a windows task on the host.

If we are sure that our site be visited every day, this is not a problem.
If not, how can we ensure that the web scheduler work all the time even if no one visit our site for days and even if the server is rebooted?

Comment: These services might help: http://www.onlinecronservices.com/

Answer (score 2):

You should install quartz.net as a windows service and access it from your web app via remoting. This will guarantee that the scheduler is always running. Instructions for setting up the scheduler as a windows service are here:
[Getting Started with Quartz.Net Part 1](http://jvilalta.blogspot.com/2009/03/getting-started-with-quartznet-part-1.html)

Comment: The best way is definitely to install Quartz.Net as a separate windows service. If you really can't do it, then maybe quartz isn't the right tool for the job here. You may want to check this [simple solution](http://stackoverflow.com/) too.

Comment: Sorry, I had the wrong link in my clipboard in my previous comment. Here is the correct link: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/07/easy-background-tasks-in-aspnet/

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to get have a Scheduled Task on the server trigger your job (by requesting the page). If you don't have a server that can do this you can use something like pingdom to hit a page at n intervals.

If you do have a server to do this you can also write a service - but for something trivial I'd just use a scheduled task.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. **But we use shared host and we cannot write a service or schedule a task on it**.

Comment: You can use a site like pingdom.com to to hit a page (that triggers your job) at n internvals then.